# Why does Google Apps script XmlElement string comparison evaluate incorrectly?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an XmlElement. I am performing a string comparison on the text it contains. By all accounts, the comparison should pass. Until recently, the code has worked successfully. However, it is now failing.

```
// caller ....
  processRow('my title', atag);
  ...

function processRow(title, rowtag) {
  // rowtag.getText() returns the string 'my title'

  if (rowtag.getText() == title) {
    // ... this section is never entered
```

In debug mode, I see two identical String objects being compared. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just do youself a favor and put right infront of the if a `Logger.log ("rowtag.getText()="+rowtag.getText()+",title="+title);` and check what's in the log...

Comment: That helped. It turns out there was an additional space in the xml text. For some reason this extra space was not present in the variable inspection window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out an extra space was present in the xml contents. The difference was not reflected in the variable inspection window; however, the logger log presented the string correctly.